# How to use Dask instead of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

i have try to use dask to replace pandas , but i don't know how to do,anyone can help?
Here is the code:

```
newfilename = "test.xlsx" 
   
    cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    data = pd.read_excel("old_test.xlsx", header=1, names=cols, usecols=cols, converters={'A': int, 'B': int, 'C': int})
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    
    df_list = np.split(df, df[df.isnull().all(1)].index)
    
    
    for i in range(1, len(df_list) + 1):
        df_list[i - 1] = df_list[i - 1].dropna(how='all')
    
    for i in range(len(df_list)):
        df_list[i] = df_list[i].groupby(['A', 'B', 'D'])['C'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))).reset_index()
        df_list[i] = df_list[i].reindex(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(newfilename, engine="xlsxwriter")
    workbook = writer.book
    
    
    for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i), index=False)
    
    writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read the Excel file in parallel, and then the `compute()` with dask [Reference](https://examples.dask.org/applications/embarrassingly-parallel.html) and [check about compute here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute.html)

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

newfilename = "test.xlsx"
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df = dd.read_excel(
    "old_test.xlsx",
    header=1,
    names=cols,
    usecols=cols,
    converters={'A': int, 'B': int, 'C': int}
).compute()

df_list = [
    df_part.dropna(how='all')
            .groupby(['A', 'B', 'D'])['C']
            .apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
            .reset_index()
            .reindex(columns=cols)
    for df_part in np.split(df, df[df.isnull().all(1)).index)
]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(newfilename, engine="xlsxwriter")

[part.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet{i}', index=False) for i, part in enumerate(df_list)]

writer.close()
```